# String greater than or less than

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
[sequences]
/a1
/a2
/a3
...
/a10
```

The query `SELECT * FROM sequences WHERE nbr <= '/a10'` should return the list above, instead it returns:

```
[results]
/a1
/a10
```

How do I make it return all the rows in the above list?

Comment: I'd remove the "a" from the string, convert it into a number, and then compare

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you on?

Comment: What SQL server is this? The answer to this question depends on the implementation.

Comment: More info needs to be given on what the data could look like, but the implementation below is not bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works as it should. To compare the numeric value, you'll have to convert these to numbers somehow. A good start would be to use `substr(yourfieldname, 3) to cut of the`/a`. Then you can use`convert` to typecast it to int, so your final query will look something like:

```
select * from sequences where convert(int, substr(nbr, 3)) <= 10
```

Mind that the exact functions and rules for converting strings to ints may very per dbms. This illustrates the general idea, though.

Comment: But keep in mind that this will query will no longer be able to use an index.

Comment: Also, you better make sure that the format isn't changing on you - e.g., abe4291032 might break you.

Comment: @duskwuff & @tofutim Both good points. If you really need to be able to use the number for indexing and searching, it is probably better to store the numeric representation of the value in a separate column. You can even do this automatically in a trigger, so you're able to implement smarter solutions for extracting the number, and you will only have to manage that functionality in a single place.

Comment: Since @mwok hasn't told us the DBMS, this may not apply, but a virtual column in Oracle would even eliminate the need for the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM sequences 
WHERE toInt(substring (nbr, 2)) <= 10;
```

Name and syntax of 'substring'-function and 'toInt' will vary from db-implementation to db-implementation.

Comment: What is the 'AS' doing there?

Comment: Sorry - the overseen rest of a previous test. I removed it.